# how to create a row that is calculated from another row automatically like how we do it in excel?

Tags: r, excel, row, calculation

does anyone know how to have a row in R that is calculated from another row automatically? i.e.

lets say in excel, i want to make a row C, which is made up of (B2/B1)

e.g. C1 = B2/B1
C2 = B3/B2
...
Cn = Cn+1/Cn

but in excel, we only need to do one calculation then drag it down. how do we do it in R?

Answer (score 1):

In R you work with columns as vectors so the operations are *vectorized*. The calculations as described could be implemented by the following commands, given a `data.frame` df (i.e. a table) and the respective column names as mentioned:

```
df["C1"] <- df["B2"]/df["B1"]
df["C2"] <- df["B3"]/df["B2"]
```

In R you usually would name the columns according to the content they hold. With that, you refer to the columns by their name, although you can also address the first column as `df[, 1]`, the first row as `df[1, ]` and so on.

*EDIT 1*:

There are multiple ways - and certainly some more elegant ways to get it done - but for understanding I kept it in simple **base R**:

Example dataset for demonstration:

```
df <- data.frame("B1" = c(1, 2, 3),
                 "B2" = c(2, 4, 6),
                 "B3" = c(4, 8, 12))
```

Column calculation:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)-1) {
  col_name <- paste0("C", i)
  df[col_name] <- df[, i+1]/df[, i]
}
```

Output:

```
  B1 B2 B3 C1 C2
1  1  2  4  2  2
2  2  4  8  2  2
3  3  6 12  2  2
```

So you iterate through the available columns B1/B2/B3. Dynamically create a column name in every iteration, based on the number of the current iteration, and then calculate the respective column contents.

*EDIT 2*:

***Rowwise***, as you actually meant it apparently, works similarly:

```
a <- c(10,15,20, 1)
df <- data.frame(a)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$b[i] <- df$a[i+1]/df$a[i]
}
```

Output:

```
   a        b
1 10 1.500000
2 15 1.333333
3 20 0.050000
4  1       NA
```

Comment: so if i were to add another column C, which formula is C1 = B2/B1 , C2 = B3/B2, i have to do it all manually? there isn't a way to just get it all done for all C?

Comment: @matcha The way you shape your data is fundamentally different in R compared to Excel.  What are B and C if if makes sense that each value of C is based on the two previous values of B?  From what I understand, each value in the "C" column should be based on the current and next values of B, in which case your general formula should I think be `Cn = Bn+1/Bn` not `Cn = Cn+1/Cn`.  What is the final value for C to be, since there will be no Bn+1?

Comment: noo, 
what im trying to say is lets say ; a<- c(10,15,20)
b<- c(1.5,1,33,0)
hello <- data.frame(a,b)

in this case, b(1,2) is a result of a(2,1)/a(1,1) which is 15/10 ... like is there any way i could have a formula so that i can get the whole calculations? if that makes sense

Comment: Yess! thiss! thank you so so so much for this! really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this just using vectors, without a `for` loop.

```
a <- c(10,15,20, 1)
df <- data.frame(a)

df$b <- c(df$a[-1], 0) / df$a

print(df)
   a        b
1 10 1.500000
2 15 1.333333
3 20 0.050000
4  1 0.000000
```

**Explanation:**

In the example data, `df$a` is the vector `10 15 20  1`.

`df$a[-1]` is the same vector with its first element removed, `15 20  1`.

And using `c()` to add a new element to the end so that the vector has the same lenght as before:

`c(df$a[-1],0)` which is `15 20  1  0`

What we want for column `b` is this vector divided by the original `df$a`.

So:

`df$b <- c(df$a[-1], 0) / df$a`